# Core Data for preloaded information

Tags: ios, core-data

im learning about core data at the moment, I can see its benefits for apps like a phonebook etc, however is core data good if your app is to contain preloaded data. For example the players of an American football team. I was using MESASqlite and manually entering the ino and then copying and pasting it into xcode to have all the players preloaded in my app.

Basically, I hear core data is not a database (according to the Apple documentation) so im a little confused.

Comment: CoreData is not a database... Sure... iPhone is not a smartphone, Mac is not a personal computer, iPod is not an MP3 player... Well played, Apple.

Comment: That's right, core-data is not a database. However iOS does include SQLite, which is a database. It has a C API. If you prefer an objective-c API, there's various wrappers such as FMDB. https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: @H2CO3: Core Data isn't a database. Core Data is an object graph management and persistence framework. One persistence option that Core Data supports is SQLite, which is a database; there are a number of others. If using SQLite, is strongly discouraged to deal with the database directly when using Core Data.

Comment: @Tim Of course, there is a slight conceptual difference which is non-negligible. That wasn't my point :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Is there any huge benefit in using coredata in an app like the one described above (view the members of a team - where adding and deleting will rarely occur)

Comment: If the preload data is small you could simplify and just use a plist file.

Comment: @Wain Will i get refused by the app store by using a MESASqlite and preload a database over core data?

Comment: MESASqlite is just a tool for creating the preload database, no, using it will have no impact.

Comment: @Wain- thanks,I havent submitted anything to the app store yet so I was just making sure - I hear they are picky - but that topic is for a different place

Comment: @Wain - the database I want to use has the extension .rdb, any problems do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CoreData as a read-only pre-loaded data-store is very possible.  In fact, CoreData's faulting mechanism may well work in your favour to keep runtime memory consumption low if the dataset is large.  Using CoreData is almost certainly easier than fetching sub-sets of records as required from an SQLite database with SQL.   CoreData also provides a solution for versioning, and model version updates.

To do this, you use an SQLite backing store and will need to write a tool to populate the initial model.   Note that whilst it's just about feasible to use an SQLite database table editor to modify individual fields, you definitely can't create or delete rows using one.

In terms of a tool for populating the initial model, it makes a lot of sense to make this a MacOSX console or Cocoa application and run it as part of the application's build process.  You include the SQLite database as a binary resource in your iOS application.

Building a graphical editing tool is actually far easier in MacOSX than iOS because of the extra KVO bindings on many controls provided by the cocoa framework - for instance, in `NSTableView`.

Alternatively, you can easily convert data from an existing format such as CSV or XML.

Answer (score 1):

I almost always use Core Data, for pre-populated or empty databases. If you have to handle persisted data, you can either use .plist or database (mostly sqlite) files. The difference is that if you use .plist files, you load the data into NSDictionary objects. On the other hand, if you use Core Data, the persisted information is loaded into "managed" objects, wich are easier to work with. You have several advantages using Core Data (manage several contexts, data model editor, caching, etc.)

If you are not familiar with Core Data you should give it a try

Comment: Thanks aprunedamtz regardless of my decision I will check it out.

Comment: The downsides of using NSDictionary are i) you must load the entire model in one go and hold it in memory.  ii) The resulting dictionary is weakly typed - so this results in considerably more code to use it.  Still, it's probably the path of least resistance and easy to implement - particularly for small models and small data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data may not truly be a database, but it holds a number of common features with SQLite databases.

Yes, Core Data is a good option. You would generally use an SQLite store to hold the data in your app. You can also write some code or a desktop app which will allow you to edit the preload database. You'd then copy the preload database to your Xcode project.

If you already have a solution using MESASqlite and everything works then there isn't a particular reason to change.

Comment: thanks, thats what I was thinking, I was interested by CoreData and thought it may be a better approach.

Comment: CoreData is a better alternative in case you want to take advantage of object mapping, which is something that SQLite does not give you out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I hear core data is not a database (according to the Apple
>   documentation) so im a little confused.

Core Data is an object persistence framework: you put objects into a store, and you can get them back out later. So it's *like* a database, and it can *use* a database for the actual storage, but if you're thinking about it in terms of tables and rows instead of object graphs you should maybe consider just using SQLite yourself. Working with objects lets you build the smarts for manipulating your data into your classes, and the objects you pull out of a data store will have those behaviors.

> is core data good if your app is to contain preloaded data.

Sure -- it's great for stuff like that. In fact, it's not uncommon to write a simple Mac program that takes data from somewhere else and adds it to a Core Data store using the same model you've created for your iOS app. You can build that data store into your iOS app along with the model, and it'll just work.